# Remove all saved USB drive letter assignments

Tags: windows, usb, windows-server-2008

Is there a location in Windows that can be used to reset all of the USB assignments, and start from scratch in Server 2008 R2?

Edit: This question involves systems that I do not own, as was to resolve an issue with backup drives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get yourself a copy of [usbdview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)
shows all assigned usb devices, including drive letters.
delete away

Answer (score 0):

I have used this article with great success. The problem was that sometimes Device Manager seemed to get confused and I would have to assign drive letters manually to make USB keys work. After cleaning out "Disk Drives" and "USB Controllers" the auto detection and letter assignment would work properly again. By "clean out" I mean deleting each of the grayed out entries. This can be quite a tedious process...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315539